# Printing EJS variable with string quotes

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to send an array from my backend in node to the frontend with EJS files.

thisis the array in backend:

```
[ '2017-12-06T13:45:00.000Z',
  '2017-12-06T13:50:00.000Z',
  '2017-12-06T13:55:00.000Z',
  '2017-12-06T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2017-12-06T14:05:00.000Z',
  '2017-12-06T14:10:00.000Z',
  '2017-12-06T14:15:00.000Z' ]
```

but when I print in EJS file like this:

```
<%= price_labels %>
```

I get this in rendered HTML:

```
[2017-12-06T13:45:00.000Z,2017-12-06T13:50:00.000Z,2017-12-06T13:55:00.000Z,2017-12-06T14:00:00.000Z,2017-12-06T14:05:00.000Z,2017-12-06T14:10:00.000Z,2017-12-06T14:15:00.000Z]
```

without string quotes.
How can I get the string quotes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to "unescaped" value, change <%= to <%- , for eg:

```
<%- price_labels %>
```

Comment: This outputs this: [[&#34;2017-12-06T13:45:00.000Z&#34;,&#34;2017-12-06T13:50:00.000Z&#34;,&#34;2017-12-06T13:55:00.000Z&#34;,&#34;2017-12-06T14:00:00.000Z&#34;,&#34;2017-12-06T14:05:00.000Z&#34;,&#34;2017-12-06T14:10:00.000Z&#34;,&#34;2017-12-06T14:15:00.000Z&#34;]]

which doesn't work either

Comment: or try using - instead of =. - means unescaped <%- price_labels %>